# regexp to remove a string?

Tags: regex, bash

I have searched the many regex questions here bug have not found out one that can remove a string of four letters...

I pass a file name to a bash script, and I want to remove the first five characters from the name, e.g.

```
myscript.sh AB2CDrestoffilename
```

which contains

```
FILENAME=$1
OUTPUTFILENAME="out$FILENAME"
```

except I would like for the OUTPUTFILENAME to be `outrestoffilename` instead of `outAB2CDrestoffilename`.

I have tried many different examples but can not get this relatively simple task to work.

Comment: @diEcho no, what is `preg.replace`?

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, you use parameter expansion:

```
A="Helloworld"; echo ${A:5}
```

In your case, say `OUTPUTFILENAME="out${FILENAME:5}"`.

No need to go overboard and cry for regexes at the slightest provocation -- Bash has plenty of power!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex for this, you can just use bash substring:

```
OUTPUTFILENAME="out${FILENAME:5}"
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regexp,

```
$ string=AB2CDrestoffilename
$ echo ${string:5}
restoffilename
```

See [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)